# R: using assign() for list elements

Tags: r, list, assign

Suppose I have an empty list `grid`. Is it possible to use assign() to assign several data frames to list elements?

```
grid <- list()

assign(grid[[1]],data.frame(x=1:4,y=5:8))
assign(grid[[2]],data.frame(x=2:4,y=6:8))
```

So that you would get an output like:

```
> grid
[[1]]
  x  y
  1  5
  2  6
  3  7
  4  8
[[2]]
  x  y
  2  6
  3  7
  4  8
```

Code:

```
grid <- list()
type = "a"

for(k in 1:3){
  assign(paste0("grid[[",k,"]]"),ifelse(type=="a",
                data.frame(x=1:4,y=5:8),
                data.frame(x=2:4,y=6:8)))
}
```

Desired output: (since type will always be "a")

```
> grid
[[1]]
  x  y
  1  5
  2  6
  3  7
  4  8
[[2]]
  x  y
  1  5
  2  6
  3  7
  4  8
[[3]]
  x  y
  1  5
  2  6
  3  7
  4  8
```

Comment: What is wrong with all the other ways of assigning to elements of a list that makes you think you need to use `assign`?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to use an `ifelse()` inside of an `assign()`. I need to conditionally choose between two dataframes and assign that chosen dataframe to an element in a list. If there is cleaner alternative to using `assign()` in this scenario, that'll be great

Comment: Could we see the code @Chani?  can't quite picture `ifelse` and `assign` together?

Comment: Why don't you ask your actual question then, with the full problem? I'm not sure why you'd need `ifelse` either, rather than just `if`.

Comment: Sorry about that, my code was a little complicated so I wanted to simplify it before posting it on SO. I've edited my original post with the less simplified code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing something, but I don't see why you need to use `assign()` at all? Doesn't this do what you wanted?

```
grid <- list()
type = "a"

for(k in 1:3){
    if(type=="a") grid[[k]] <- data.frame(x=1:4,y=5:8)
}
```

EDIT:

```
for(k in 1:3){
    if(type=="a") grid[[k]] <- data.frame(x=1:4,y=5:8)
    if(type=="b") grid[[k]] <- data.frame(x=2:4,y=6:8)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, However I want there to be another dataframe, for instance if `type="b"`.